# plotting direction field for systems of three equations in SageMath using maxima

Tags: matplotlib, differential-equations, sage, maxima, computation

I would like to plot the direction field for a system of 3 or more equations in SageMath using Maxima. I know how to do this for a system of 2 equations. I don't know what to modify so that I extend it to 3 or more equations. I tried the following example for a system of two equations

```
  maxima('plotdf([x,-y],[x,y],[x,-2,2],[y,-2,2])')
```

I was thinking for the three or more equations I simply have to add more varibles like

```
maxima('plotdf([x,-y,z],[x,y,z],[x,-2,2],[y,-2,2],[z,-2,2])')
```

but its not working. I dont know what am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Maxima documentation for plotdf](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/de/maxima_66.html) makes the syntax clear.  I'm not sure what a slope/direction field would look like for more equations unless you had more variables, but then it would have to be in three dimensions, which is not supported.

In any case I'm surprised this worked from within Sage; you must have had wxmaxima or something analogous already there.

Finally, note that [SageMath has slope fields natively](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/plot_field.html), though this may not correspond with your workflow.

Comment: Okay. I thought it was possible doing some fix so that it should work for 3-dimensions